# how can I change top-margin the right way if multiple css class assigned?

Tags: css

I assigned these classes **menu second_menu menu_about_author** to ul so the html code looks like `<ul class="menu second_menu menu_about_author">` I wanted this ul to have the same properties like menu and second_menu and then I wanted to move the menu_about_author little bit down.

I did so by `.menu_about_author { margin-top:40px; }` but it didn't work

any idea why *the margin-top:40px;* is crossed? the link to the image is  [1]: http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/882/58daeef0c3c846e4a8d6321.png

[alt text http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/882/58daeef0c3c846e4a8d6321.png](http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/882/58daeef0c3c846e4a8d6321.png)

Comment: three correct answers bellow. which one is the best? The most correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
.custom .menu.second_menu.menu_about_author { margin-top:40px; }
```

or

```
.custom .second_menu.menu_about_author { margin-top:40px; }
```

as selector

otherwise your margin is overwritten by the second_menu margin

probably also

```
.custom .menu_about_author { margin-top:40px; }
```

will work if this code is after `.custom .second_menu`

Comment: great, great, great! I think you answered another of my questions :-) Thank you @choise could you recommend any css tutorial I am really confused how to `address` css elements

Comment: ja, ich verstehe (is that correct?) not sure if I can remmember from high school

Comment: Remember that multiple class selectors like `.class1.class2` don't work in IE6. Seems to me that 'menu_about_author' is addressing a specific menu, so would be better suited to an ID:

.custom #menu_about_author.second_menu { margin-top:40px; }

Which, I think, is better HTML style and gets around the IE6 problem as well. ID's have a higher specificity, too - which will solve your inheritance problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because `.custom .second_menu` has higher Specificity than `.menu_about_author`

In other words, `.custom .second_menu` is **more specific** than `.menu_about_author`, so it take priority.

You can learn about this here...

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/

You can solve the problem by doing something like this...

```
.custom .menu_about_author
```

or

```
.custom ul.menu_about_author
```

Other answers also have suggestions that will work by making your author entry more specific.

Comment: pity that I read your answer later than the other one. I love the way you explain this to me. Thank you soooooo much for the link. I do need some study. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To quickly se if its an inheritance problem, you can use !important

```
.menu_about_author { margin-top:40px !important; }
```

Comment: interesting. `!important` works too. So now the BIG question is what should I use to fix that? I have three right answers. Which one is the best or it doesn't matter?